# Select field multiple indexes of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
recept_id raavare_id nom_netto tolerance
       1           1        10       0.1
       1           2         2       0.1
       1           5         2       0.1
       2           1        10       0.1
       2           3         2       0.l
       2           5       1.5       0.1
       2           6       1.5       0.1
       3           1        10       0.1
       3           4       1.5       0.1
       3           5       1.5       0.1
       3           6         1       0.1
       3           7         1       0.1
```

I'm trying to select the row where `raavare_id` is equal to 6 and 7. so i'm trying to select the row where `recept_id` is equal to `3`.

Tried this, but obviously it doesn't work cause you can't select a field with 2 values:
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE raavare_id="6" AND raavare_id="7"`

This doesn't work either, since it will select other rows like `recept_id=2` because it has a `raavare_id=6`, but i want to select the row(s) where BOTH `raavare_id` is equal to 6 and 7 AND has the same `recept_id`:
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE raavare_id="6" OR raavare_id="7"`

## EDIT:

Forgot to mention that i am not allowed to use `recept_id` in the sql-query. I need to select the row where `raavare_id` is 6 and 7 and both has the same `recept_id`. But the `recept_id` must not be in the query.

Comment: try `IN` operator, `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE raavare_id IN (6,7)`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on *the recept_id must not be in the query*. Don't you want to use it in a `WHERE` clause? And what is the reason for this?

Comment: Yea i don't want to use it in the where clause. Because that's the thing i want to get from the query, so there is no point in having it in the where clause.

Comment: So you want `recept_id` to be the **only** field returned by the query?

Comment: Well yea that's the part i want to get from the query. But it shouldn't make a big difference in the sql-statement. It's just the `SELECT recept_id` instead of `SELECT *`

Comment: But if it makes it easier to answer the question, feel free to only return the `recept_id` :)

Comment: Please check the edit I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with IN , group by and a having clause:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE recept_id in(SELECT recept_id
                   FROM YourTable
                   WHERE raavare_id in('6','7')
                   GROUP BY recept_id
                   having count(distinct raavare_id) = 2)
```

Or with exists()

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE exists(SELECT 1
             FROM YourTable s
             WHERE t.recept_id = s.recept_id and s.raavare_id in('6','7')
             GROUP BY s.recept_id
             having count(distinct s.raavare_id) = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE recept_id IN (
   SELECT recept_id
   FROM table_name 
   WHERE raavare_id IN (6,7)
   GROUP BY raavare_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT raavare_id) = 2)
```

The subquery used by the `IN` operator returns `recept_id =3` because this is the id value that belongs to a group of `raavare_id` having *both* (6, 7) values.

**Edit:**

If you only want to get the `recept_id` value, then just use the subquery:

```
SELECT recept_id
FROM table_name 
WHERE raavare_id IN (6,7)
GROUP BY raavare_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT raavare_id) = 2
```

Comment: It didn't return anything :/

Comment: @ahmadalbayati What is the data type of `raavare_id`?

Comment: int(11) jalksdjsajdlksaj

Comment: Thank you for the help, but @Yossi got the right answer. Thank you for sticking with me though ^^'

Comment: @ahmadalbayati Did you use `IN ('6','7')` instead of `IN (6,7)`?

Comment: @ahmadalbayati Ok, never mind. Mine answer is also correct anyway.